# Is there any way to send mail automatically from an application?

Tags: android, email

I have created an application that gets the location information(latitude,longitude,altitude) and sends email using ACTION_SEND to some gmail account. But i am unable to send auto generated mail to that account. I need to send mail whenever the location changes. But my application is displaying the list of choosers available. Please give me some idea.

Comment: Use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2033124/940096)

Comment: @SpK Thanks for the response but that needs a button to be clicked for sending email right ? I need some idea to send email automatically whenever you run that application.

Comment: Yes, Instead of button click. Do the changes with your needs. Simply. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you case, you need to send mail when your location has been changed right. So, you've [onLocationChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html#onLocationChanged%28android.location.Location%29) from you class. From, there you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2033124/940096) example for sending mail.

For example,

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
{
    // Call the GmailSender as per the example
    try {   
        GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("username@gmail.com", "password");
        sender.sendMail("This is Subject",   
                        "This is Body",   
                        "user@gmail.com",   
                        "user@yahoo.com");   
        } catch (Exception e) {   
            Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);   
        }
}
```

So, you can simply send the mail when your location will changed instead of sending mail through Button click.